# Is there any better way to display the value of the table without creating too many VIEW?

Tags: sql, oracle

so I want the following table to be differentiate using a new column that follows its stage code. For example:

```
    Original Data
    |JS_CASEKEY|JS_STAGE_CODE|JS_ENDDATE |
    | -------- | ----------- | --------- |
    | 0001     | ARRCV1      | 20/02/2022|
    | 0002     | CUSTEXEC    | 01/02/2022|
    | 0003     | ARRCV1      | <NULL>    |

    Expected Results
    |JS_CASEKEY|ARRCV1 END DATE|CUSTEXEC END DATE|
    | -------- | ------------- | ----------------|
    | 0001     | 20/02/2022    | <NULL>          |
    | 0002     | <NULL>        | 01/02/2022      |
    | 0003     | <NULL>        | <NULL>          |
```

As for now my solution were creating two different VIEW for each of the different stage code but in terms of maintainability would be a hassle if the stage code got many different values.
The code for the view are as follows

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_CUSTEXEC_ENDDATE AS select JS_CASEKEY,  
    JS_ENDDATE from jcheckstage where js_stage_code = 'CUSTEXEC';
```

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_ARRCV1_ENDDATE AS select JS_CASEKEY as  
    JS_CASEKEY1, JS_ENDDATE as JS_ENDDATE1 from jcheckstage where  
    js_stage_code = 'ARRCV1';
```

Then in the select statement I would just include the following to make use of the two VIEWs i created

```
    select JS_ENDDATE as "Customer Execution End Date", JS_ENDDATE1  
    as "AR 1 End Date";
```

This method would be okay to maintain if there is only few different values for the stage code but any more values for it would mean a lot more VIEWs to create and are going to be hard to manage. Is there a simpler way to do this or any other way that I didn't discover yet?

Comment: Post your data and desired results as text, not images.  I'm not seeing how you get from the original data to the expected results so please explain in words what logic you are implementing.  If you have already created views that solve the problem and are just looking to simplify your code, please post the views that you've created.

Comment: sorry for that, i included the progress of mine

Comment: Are you wanting one column per stage code, like a pivot table?

Comment: for now i want only for those two stage but in future maybe ill include other stage

Answer (score 2):

You can use some code like this:

```
with data ( JS_CASEKEY,JS_STAGE_CODE,JS_ENDDATE ) as (
    select '0001'     , 'ARRCV1'      , '20/02/2022' from dual union all
    select '0002'     , 'CUSTEXEC'    , '01/02/2022' from dual union all
    select '0003'     , 'ARRCV1'      ,null from dual
)
select
JS_CASEKEY, max(case when JS_STAGE_CODE='ARRCV1' then JS_ENDDATE else null end) as arrcv_end_date,
 max(case when JS_STAGE_CODE='CUSTEXEC' then JS_ENDDATE else null end) as CUSTEXEC_end_date
from data
group by JS_CASEKEY
/
JS_C ARRCV_END_ CUSTEXEC_E
---- ---------- ----------
0001 20/02/2022
0002            01/02/2022
0003
```

or also use pivot, like this

```
select *
from data
pivot (max(JS_ENDDATE) for JS_STAGE_CODE  in ('ARRCV1' as arrcv_end_date, 'CUSTEXEC' as CUSTEXEC_end_date))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This certainly helps with some tweaking i think i could make use of this. Thanks again!